# What's so illegal about this operation

Tags: c, sequence-points

Namely code similar to this, making the printout undefined.

```
int a=41; a++ & printf("%d\n", a);
```

I don't know what exactly this operation is called.

Comment: Notice, instead, that `a++ && printf("%d\n", a);` is perfectly defined, since `&&` introduces a sequence point - the left-hand operand of `&&` is guaranteed to be always evaluated before the right-hand one (which isn't even be evaluated if the LHO is false).

Comment: @MitchWheat: I would've have duplicated it if I knew the name.

Comment: It's more or less a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc, although as usual this specific example isn't in that question. What's illegal about it is that it admits a valid order of evaluation in which it modifies `a` and also reads `a` for a purpose other than determining the value to be assigned, without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: I guess there isn't a special name for this type of undefined behavior?

Comment: @stanigator: You could call it UB due to "insufficient sequence points", if you need a short phrase to refer to it.

Comment: @staginator: It's modifying an object and reading it without an intervening sequence point.  The reason it gets asked so often is because anyone who knows what "sequence point" means knows the answer to this question, and therefore anyone that wants to know the answer doesn't know the search term.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks. Sorry for adding overhead.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Interestingly though, this question was tagged with sequence point :).  (Though I guess that does not imply that the poster knows what it means.)

Comment: @Corbin: I tagged it as sequence point b/c I thought it's related to something wrong with it, although I didn't know it's a type of UB.

Comment: @MatteoItalia yes definitely, or else you couldn't rely on short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that it is not specified which is evaluated first, the `printf` or the `a++`, and since one has a side effect on the other (you either read `a` then write it then read it again, or read it then read it then write it), you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: Note: It's been observed that some compilers are not even consistent about which way they interpret the code.

Comment: @Dietrich: quite right too. The order of evaluation could depend on (for example) optimization level, or the compiler could choose a different order as likely to be most efficient in different contexts, depending on some subtle detail of the state that the compiler predicts for the instruction pipeline when the statement comes to be executed. Since order is unspecified, it could even hypothetically leave the decision to some kind of monstrous profile-guided, code-mutating runtime optimizer (aka "a modern CPU"), so  the order starts out one way, then flips to the other.